# ProcessException: Process "...\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally: Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter

**Summary**
I'm starting studying Flutter with Firebase. I have some experience with using Firebase through Kotlin android. When run a new flutter application which is completely new one through Android Studio, it works well. However, after finish settings for Firebase such as...

1. Adding google-services.json from Firebase project.
2. app/build.gradle
   `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
3. android/build.gradle
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`
4. pubspec.yaml
   `firebase_core: ^0.2.5  # add dependency for Firebase Core`

and below are
**versions of**

```
android studio 3.4.1

flutter --version
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2d2a1ffec9 (10 days ago) • 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0

gradle version : gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

When I ran, I've got
**Error**

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\DEV\flutter_firebase1\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\DEV\flutter_firebase1\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
  Command: D:\DEV\flutter_firebase1\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.`
```

I swear I completely followed instruction of documentation of Firebase. And I tried it again with completely new project. How can I do for it?

Comment: found any solve yet?

Answer (score 3):

In my case.

Solved by updating Project level `build.gradle`
under dependencies classpath 
`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`

[image]

and in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to `gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

[image]